# App crashing when pressing a button behind keyboard

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

The app I'm creating is crashing whenever a button is pressed that is behind the keyboard.

I have the following view:

```
struct LoginSheetView: View {
 // Variables Here
    var body: some View {
        SwiftyHUDView(isShowing: self.$isLoading) {
            VStack{
                Text("Login")
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                    .fontWeight(.semibold)
                    .padding(.bottom, 20)
                TextField("Username", text: self.$username)
                    .padding(.bottom, 20)
                    .autocapitalization(.none)
                    .textContentType(UITextContentType.username)
                SecureField("Password", text: self.$password)
                    .padding(.bottom, 20)
                    .textContentType(UITextContentType.password)
                Button(action: {
                    self.isLoading = true
                    if(!self.username.isEmpty  && !self.password.isEmpty){
                        self.databaseCalls.login(username: self.username, password: self.password){ b in
                            self.isLoading = false
                            print("is loading: \(self.isLoading)")
                            if(b){
                                self.loginStatus = true
                                self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                            }else{
                                self.showingAlert = true
                            }
                        }

                    }


                }){
                    Text("Login")
                        .frame(width: 220, height: 60)
                        .cornerRadius(15.0)
                }
            }
            .alert(isPresented: self.$showingAlert) {
                Alert(title: Text("Loging failed"), message: Text("Wrong username or password"), dismissButton: .default(Text("Got it!")))
            }
            .padding()

        }

    }
}
```

Which looks like this:

[image]

Whenever I press the button *Login* while the keyboard is up I get the following error in the file `AppDelegate`:

`Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)`

This error does not happen if I press `return` on the keyboard then press the `Login` button.

Any ideas on what's causing the error ?

**NOTE:**
*I removed some code (variables declarations, padding, colors etc) to make it easier to digest*

Answer (score 0):

I've added:

`UIApplication.shared.sendAction(#selector(UIResponder.resignFirstResponder), to:nil, from:nil, for:nil)`

inside the button action and it has fixed the problem. Does anyone know if this is the correct way of approaching the issue ?